# changing rgb to grayscale in c++

Tags: c++

i am trying to convert a rgb image to a grayscale one
this is the code i am using to generate random pixels for the existing image ... i am using a .h file to generate the output file too ...
This is the image.h file : https://www65.zippyshare.com/v/yWLb2IjG/file.html
and this is a the used sample : https://www65.zippyshare.com/v/Cx5U4cua/file.html

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include"image.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    Image im=readPPM("./xmas.ppm");

    int largeur=im.w, hauteur=im.h;
    cout<<"Ouverture d'une image de largeur "<<largeur<<" et de hauteur "<<hauteur<<endl;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int j=0;j<largeur;j++){
        for (int i=0;i<hauteur;i++){
            im(j,i).r +=(rand()%100)/300.0; 
            im(j,i).g +=(rand()%100)/300.0; 
            im(j,i).b +=(rand()%100)/300.0; 
        }
    }

    savePPM(im,"./out.ppm");
    return 0;
}
```

for the grayscale i have tried to add :
im(j,i) +=0.2126*im(j,i).r+0.7152*im(j,i).g+0.0722*im(j,i).b;

but it does not work 
i tried it also with 33% for each color and 0.3 for red 0.57 for green and 0.11 for blue and same result . it does not work

Comment: A grayscale image in RGB is just an image where each pixel's RGB components are equal.

Comment: Did you mean to use `+=` there? - as opposed to `*=`.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the `rand()` part in the example code. Seems to reset the pixels to some random value and not have anything to do with grayscale. And if you want to generate a random image why do you need to read a file?

Comment: Grayscale simply means red, green, and blue are equal. Have you tried averaging the pixel values, like `avg = (im(j,i).r + (im(j,i).g + (im(j,i).b) / 3;` and assigning the average to all three colour components?

Comment: well i do have a read file and i am just like putting covers of pixels on it . my english is bad i have explained the best way i can ...

Comment: @alterigel yes i have tried it before ... maybe i am not using it the right way but i have tried it

Comment: Why don't you show what you tried with the RGB to  grayscale conversion. It seems the question is about that but the code is not.

Comment: @SamiAlaa by _assigning_, I meant something like `im(j,i).r = avg;` and not `im(j,i) += avg;`

Comment: as i have mentioned i have generated all the pixels randomly and after that i tried to grayscale it using what i have generated . so i used the : im(j,i) +=0.2126*im(j,i).r+0.7152*im(j,i).g+0.0722*im(j,i).b; and i have put it in the for loop

Comment: What I meant is to edit your code. Remove the part about rand() and put in your RGB to grayscale conversion code. That would be a better question. If you can also show a picture of the before and after (again with the random pixel values removed).

Comment: @alterigel yes thats what i have tried and it keeps showing me a black and white picture . not grayscale only black and white like it s painted .

Comment: @drescherjm i will try it rn

Comment: @SamiAlaa how are pixel values being stored? Are they integers between 0-255, for example? Are they floats or doubles from 0 to 1?

Comment: @drescherjm i have tried giving the r g b same value without rand but it shows me a white picture

Comment: @alterigel the code used to generate the pixels is a .h file which is available online i am using it cause it helped me before so i am not the one who wrote it but i believe that the values are doubles

Comment: The download site is blocked for me.

Comment: `im(j,i) +=0.2126*im(j,i).r+0.7152*im(j,i).g+0.0722*im(j,i).b` should be `im(j,i) =0.2126*im(j,i).r+0.7152*im(j,i).g+0.0722*im(j,i).b`. You don't want to add to the previous value. Also you probably need to set red, green and blue. Not sure what Image supports.

Comment: what is the best website to upload the files on ?

Comment: @drescherjm and yes you are totally right . it worked fine now thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple fix, but I'm going to explain what's going on first.

> for the grayscale i have tried to add : `im(j,i) +=0.2126*im(j,i).r+0.7152*im(j,i).g+0.0722*im(j,i).b;`

Let's look at why this "doesn't work"...

So, `Image::operator(int,int)` returns a `Rgb&`.  At least we know we're dealing with a *reference* so we should be able to modify the value.

Now, you are invoking `Rgb::operator+=(float)` which doesn't exist.  But this won't be a compiler error because of `Rgb& operator += (const Rgb &rgb)`, and there *is* an implicit constructor `Rgb(float)`.  So what is that doing?  Let's break it down:

1. You calculate a grayscale value based on luminance: `0.2126*im(j,i).r+0.7152*im(j,i).g+0.0722*im(j,i).b`
2. The `+=` operator implicitly constructs a grayscale Rgb value from that, and *adds* it to the existing image value.

The above description looks like this in code:

```
float lum = 0.2126f * im(j,i).r + 0.7152f * im(j,i).g + 0.0722f * im(j,i).b;
img(j,i) += Rgb(lum);
```

By *adding* it, you are taking the existing color value and offsetting each channel by the same amount.  This results in a new color that is much brighter.

Instead, you want to change the value to be the new one you just calculated:

```
img(j,i) = Rgb(lum);
```

I hope you can see the difference.